# Extract numbers from string only separated by space or "-"

Tags: sql-server

I have a column with string I will to extract min 5 digits numbers. Between separation can be only space or dash (-) not text. How can I find those ?

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_Persons (
    Address varchar(255)
)

insert into tmp_Persons values ('1 street 10 may 1945')
insert into tmp_Persons values ('1234-567 street 1945')
insert into tmp_Persons values ('street 1234567')
insert into tmp_Persons values ('123 456 7 street')
insert into tmp_Persons values ('12 street 5678-123')
insert into tmp_Persons values ('123-45-678 potato')

select * from tmp_Persons
```

```
Desired output
NULL
1234567
1234567
1234567
5678123
12345678
```

Comment: T-SQL is not your friend here. I suggest using a different language that supports regex or implementing CLR functions for Regex functionality.

Comment: Why isn't the first row `1101945` and the second `12345671945`?

Comment: *"Between separation can be only space or dash (-) not text"* @Charlieface . `'street'` is neither a hyphen (`-`) or a space (` `).

Comment: And what would the result be for `12345 street 5678-123` do you want both numbers separately or together or only one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code(GetNumbers) to extract numbers
First, it replace a space and a dash, then separates the numbers, and finally checks if the length is greater than 7.

```
select a.Address,* from tmp_Persons a
outer  apply(
        select * from string_split( [dbo].[GetNumbers]( replace(replace( a.Address,'-',''),' ','')),',')
        where len( value)>=7
)aa
```

GetNumbers

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNumbers]
(  @stInput VARCHAR(max))
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @stInput = REPLACE(@stInput,',','')
    DECLARE @intAlpha INT
    DECLARE @intNumber INT
    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%', @stInput)
    SET @intNumber = PATINDEX('%[0-9,]%', @stInput)
    IF @stInput IS NULL OR @intNumber = 0
        RETURN '';

    WHILE @intAlpha > 0
    BEGIN
        IF (@intAlpha > @intNumber)
        BEGIN
            SET @intNumber = PATINDEX('%[0-9,]%', SUBSTRING(@stInput, @intAlpha, LEN(@stInput)) )
            SELECT @intNumber = CASE WHEN @intNumber = 0 THEN LEN(@stInput) ELSE @intNumber END
        END
        SET @stInput = STUFF(@stInput, @intAlpha, @intNumber - 1,',' );
        SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9,]%', @stInput )
        SET @intNumber = PATINDEX('%[0-9,]%', SUBSTRING(@stInput, @intAlpha, LEN(@stInput)) )
        SELECT @intNumber = CASE WHEN @intNumber = 0 THEN LEN(@stInput) ELSE @intNumber END
    END
    IF (RIGHT(@stInput, 1) = ',')
        SET @stInput = LEFT(@stInput, LEN(@stInput) - 1)
    IF (LEFT(@stInput, 1) = ',')
        SET @stInput = RIGHT(@stInput, LEN(@stInput) - 1)
    RETURN ISNULL(@stInput,0)
END
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to extract zip code from address for a project  regardless of their position within the string. I wrote this code. Finally, you should note that this function exists in new versions of SQL server. It is also important how many digits of the numbers are to be extracted

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       SUBSTRING(value, PATINDEX('%[0-9]{1,}%', value), LEN(value)) AS extracted_number
  FROM tableName
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(columnName, '-')  
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]{5,}%', value) > 0
```

Comment: SQL Server's pattern matching doesn't support the syntax you've used with braces (`{}`).  They would just be treated as literal braces.